# Regex for absolute url

Tags: python, regex

I am searching quite a while for a regex compatible with Python's `re` module for finding all URLs in HTML document and I cannot find it except one that was only to able to check whether an url is valid or invalid (with `match` method). I want to do simple

```
import requests
html_response = requests.get('http://example.com').text
urls = url_pattern.findall(html_response)
```

I suppose needed regex (if exists) would be complex enough to take into consideration a bunch of special cases of urls so it cannot be some oneline code.

Comment: Don't use regex to parse html. Use [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) instead (or the [html parser in the standard lib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html) )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use **BeautifulSoup** instead.It's simple to use and allows you to parse pages with HTML.

See this answer [How to extract URLs from an HTML page in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15517483/how-to-extract-urls-from-a-html-page-in-python)